# Automatically create and upload a Youtube video from my cloud storage

Tags: python, json, post, youtube, upload

I was pondering the idea of a script/program that will auto upload to Youtube from cloud storage. I'm sure this has already been done and would appreciate it if someone could put me on the right path.

Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your are not giving a lot of detail informations e.g. what cloud you use? Maybe i'm keeping it way too simple though:

I guess this problem can be splited in to two parts:

1. Download to video to your local system. There are a lot of articles/documentation for all kind of cloud storage provider e.g. [google cloud](https://medium.com/@sandeepsinh/multiple-file-download-form-google-cloud-storage-using-python-and-gcs-api-1dbcab23c44)
2. Use the provided [YouTube API documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video) to upload your video you just fetched to your local system.
3. You may want to delete the video on your local file system.

Comment: I wanted to do this for audiobooks stored on icerbox. I don't really want to direct download to my laptop. Ideally I would run theprogram on a remote server. The server would compile a video using audio and picture then upload to youtube